# android java loops versus statements which is better for performance?

Tags: java, android

I am asking this question because consider following scenario:

In my android app, if there are 10 items, then for selecting 3 items I check current range. For e.g. if current range is 3 to 5 (i.e. 3rd, 4th and 5th item) then I want to treat less than 3 i.e. 0 to 2 items differently and greater than 3 items differently and range items i.e. 3rd, 4th and 5th item differently. So I can do it in two ways:

**1st approach) By using multiple for loops like:**

```
for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
{
  //treat less than 3 items in this loop
} 

for(int i=3;i<5;i++)
{
  //treat range items i.e. 3rd, 4th and 5th items in this loop
} 

for(int i=4;i<9;i++)
{
  //treat greater than 3 items in this loop
}
```

**2nd approach) By using if statement in for loop like:**

```
for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
{
  if(i<3)
  {
    //treat less than 3 items
  }
  else if(i>3)
  {
    //treat greater than 3 items 
  }
  else
  {
    //treat range items i.e. 3rd, 4th and 5th items 
  }
}
```

So which approach is better for performance? Using multiple for loops is better or using if statement inside one single for loop is better? What if I want to increase conditions? Does incrementing conditions will impact performance?

**Edit 1:**
Actually those items are RecyclerView items. If item is not present in range then I will recycle it. And one more thing, each and every single item contains WebView and one coordinator layout also; Actually I am using RecyclerView as a tab manager for my browser. And its one item represents one browsing tab.

Comment: The performance difference is almost certainly irrelevant. Go for the one you find easiest to read.

Comment: I'm not sure there actually is a difference (the compiler might also optimize the code) and thus I'd not bother. Most likely you won't run into any performance issues with this and if you are then the problem most likely is somewhere else and you'd need to properly profile your application. Why exactly are you worried about performance here?

Comment: I think that 1st is faster, in this way You don't do unnecessary checking in which range is `i`

Comment: @Thomas In general, java compilers do close to zero optimisation on the source code side of things. Almost all the "magic" happens by the JIT at runtime (where I admit: I dont know how "smart" the android "jvm" acts here).

Comment: Check Edit 1 please. What are your thoughts about using correct approach in that case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ask yourself how many "instructions" would need to be executed for your two options. In the first example, you have 3 loops, but each loop works on "1 third" of the data. Option two loops once, but "all" elements, and for "all" elements, it runs those if/else cascade.

Thus, technically, the first solution leads to less instructions.

But the real answer is: unless we are talking the processing of thousands of elements, it really doesn't matter. Java performance doesn't come out of clever source code. It comes out of the simple code, that the just-in-time compiler can turn into optimal machine code ... if necessary.

Beyond that: you should only worry about performance if you encounter real issues.  Sure, avoid doing outright stupid things in your source code, but remember: modern CPUs, even in mobile devices are pretty powerful. A few more here or there are almost without effect. One logging call, or DB fetch, or call to a remote server might carry a thousand times more "penalty" compared to "3 loops" vs "1 loop with 3 ifs".

Thus the real answer is: try to write easy to read and understand code. In your case: in your first example, you could put each for-loop in its own method. Which would then enable the JIT to maybe do *inlining* of the method body, and such things.

You see, when you write simple code, you make it easier for the JIT to do its job. And: if you later find "performance sucks", then *easy to read* code is also easier to change.

Comment: So conclusion: 1st approach is better? Because it is moderately easy to read and it has less instructions?

Comment: Yes, I would agree to that.

Comment: Please check Edit 1. What are your thoughts about using 1st approach in that type of case which contains RecyclerView as a tab manager.

Comment: Please avoid coming back and changing the whole context of a question. I am not that deep into android programming ... but I really dont see how that would make any difference.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for your help and time.

Comment: while i don't disagree with this answer or anything you've said, i'm not sure how much of this actually has to do with 1) android and 2) stack overflow, it seems to be a question better suited for software engineering perhaps, although that's just my opinion

Answer (score 1):

It is not a matter of efficiency.

Separate loops may ensure that all indices are treated:

```
int i = 0;
for (; i < 3; i++) {
    // treat less than 3 items in this loop
} 
for (; i < 6; i++) {
    // treat range items i.e. 3rd, 4th and 5th items in this loop
} 
for (; i < 9; i++) {
    // treat greater than 3 items in this loop
}
```

Or:

```
int i = 0;
while (i < 3) {
    // treat less than 3 items in this loop
    ++i;
} 
while (i < 6) {
    // treat range items i.e. 3rd, 4th and 5th items in this loop
    ++i;
} 
while (i < 9) {
    // treat greater than 3 items in this loop
    ++i;
}
```

Notice `< 5` changed to `< 6`.

---

It's slightly better, as the semantics/meaning of the conditions, is more self-explaining. So it is more readable.

Comment: So, do you mean 3 separate loops approach is better instead of if statement with various conditions in one single for loop?

Comment: Yes, as the semantics, meaning of the conditions, is more self-explaining.